# i am getting cannot be used as a function error?

Tags: c++

I am not getting my desired result, help me around this thing. What is the error ? 
What functions should go into the header file?
What functions shouldn't?
my main file -->

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include "flight.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
int rows=0,cols=0;
int ** readDurations= NULL;
int * cities = NULL;
string duration = "durations.txt";
readDurations(duration, rows, cols);
}
```

my flight.cpp file -->

```
#ifndef FLIGHT_H    
#define FLIGHT_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// inputs the file fileName, creates a dynamic 2D array, and returns it
int** readDurations(string filename, int& rows, int& cols)
{
    ifstream myfile("durations.txt");
    if (myfile)
    cout << "Error in opening file!";
    myfile >> rows;
    cols=rows;

    int **readDurations = new int *[rows];
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        readDurations[i] = new int [cols];
    }


    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<cols;j++){
            myfile >> readDurations[i][j];
        }
    }

    return readDurations;

}
```

my header file

```
#ifndef FLIGHT_H
#define FLIGHT_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

// inputs the file fileName, creates a dynamic 2D array, and returns it
int** readDurations(string fileName, int& rows, int& cols);
#endif
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: `int ** readDurations= NULL;` isn't a function in that scope.

Answer (score 4):

in `main()`:

```
int ** readDurations= NULL;
// ...
readDurations(duration, rows, cols); // it thinks this is an int**
```

You are using the same name for two different things.
Put your function in a namespace, then call it fully qualified: `myNameSpace::readDurations(...);`

But you aren't using the `readDurations` variable declared here anyway. Get rid of it.